# Chart.js - How to create a different global configuration between the x axis and the y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I use Chart.js (https://www.chartjs.org/) on several pages of my site to display different charts

To simplify the addition and modification of these charts I added lines in my script to configure Chart.js differently from the basic options

```
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display =  true
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.drawBorder =  true
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color =  '#f5f5f5'
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = true;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.fontSize = 13
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.fontColor = '#373d3f'
....
```

The problem is that on some options I want different values for the x and y axis, for example for the `drawOnChartArea` option

And I don't know how to do it, because it doesn't work:

```
Chart.defaults.scale.xAxes.gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false
Chart.defaults.scale.yAxes.gridLines.drawOnChartArea = true
```

So, I am still forced to add in the options of all my graphics these lines:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawOnChartArea: false,
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawOnChartArea: true,
      }   
    }],
  },
}
```

**How to create a different global configuration between the x axis and the y axis?**

Is there another way to create a global configuration (cleaner? More efficient?) for Chart.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chart.defaults` contains chart `type` specific sections that include the `scales` option. You can use `console.log(Chart.defaults)` to find out how it looks like.

`Chart.defaults.bar` for example is defined as follows:

```
"bar": {
  "hover": {
    "mode": "label"
  },
  "scales": {
    "xAxes": [{
      "type": "category",
      "offset": true,
      "gridLines": {
        "offsetGridLines": true
      }
    }],
    "yAxes": [{
      "type": "linear"
    }]
  }
}
```

If the parent object of a nested property is already defined, you can directly assign its value.

```
Chart.defaults.bar.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false;
```

If however the parent object is not yet defined, you need to assign the property together with its parent object or object hierarchy. When you do this, make sure to also take over previously existing default values.

```
Chart.defaults.bar.legend = { display: false };
```

Please have a look at below code sample.

```js
Chart.defaults.bar.legend = {
  display: false
};
Chart.defaults.bar.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false;
Chart.defaults.bar.scales.yAxes[0] = {
  type: 'linear',
  gridLines: {
    drawOnChartArea: false
  },
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true
  }
};

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [25, 18, 8, 13],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I did not understand everything for the parent properties, for example how to use ``drawOnChartArea = false`` for a line type chart?

Comment: @Rocsta: In case of the `xAxes`, this would be `Chart.defaults.line.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.drawOnChartArea = false;`

Comment: When I use your solution, I have this error: ``jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'drawOnChartArea' of undefined``

Comment: @Rocstar: I was wrong. since `gridLines` is not yet defined, it should be `Chart.defaults.line.scales.xAxes[0] = {
  type: "category",
  id: "x-axis-0",
  gridLines: {
    drawOnChartArea: false
  }
}`

Comment: Thank you it works and I understand the concept better

Comment: This answer is for chart.js v2, which is outdated at this point. For v3, the best thing you can do is `console.log(Chart.defaults)` and `console.log(Chart.overrides)` and you can start to see how all the config data is organized